# Basics of extreme values / high-water marks?

Tags: references, extreme-value

With real-valued $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, define
$Max_n := \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ record value or high-water mark
$NextMax_n :=$ the next greater high water, $Max_{n+m} > Max_n$
$Up_n := NextMax_n - Max_n$.

Can anyone suggest an introduction to estimating $NextMax$ and $Up$, for

1. $X$ i.i.d. from a known distribution,
2. nonparametric, estimate-as-you-go?

Either a book chapter or an online stats course would do nicely.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to estimate? If you want to estimate maximum of the data as each new observation arrives the most simple estimate is the sample maximum. Maybe you want some distribution properties, like mean, variance, quantiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuart Coles' [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852334592) on extreme value statistics would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks Dikran -- however book publishers have also studied extreme values; would anyone know of an online introduction ?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=kXCg8B5xSUwC&lpg=PP1&dq=Statistics+of+Extremes+gumbel&pg=PP1&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false